# Posição errada de posts no Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Imagens quebradas, deveria ser um post embaixo do outro, completando 3 posts:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Index.php

```
<div id="bloco_um">
    <div id="destaque">
        <?php query_posts('showposts=1&category_name=noticias&offset=1');?>
        <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <a href="<?php the_Permalink()?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/imagens/exemplo.jpg" width="340" height="170" border="0"  />
                <span><?php the_title();?></span>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile; else:?>

        <?php endif;?>                
    </div><!-- destaque -->

    <div id="outros_destaques">                
        <div class="outro_destaque">
        <?php query_posts('showposts=3&category_name=noticias&offset=1');?>
        <?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>
            <a href="<?php the_Permalink()?>">
                <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/imagens/exemplo.jpg" width="110" height="70" border="0"  />
                <span><?php the_title();?></span>
            </a>
        <?php endwhile; else:?>

        <?php endif;?>                    
    </div><!-- outro_destaque -->
</div><!-- outros_destaques -->
```

A ideia é mostrar a mensagem principal do lado esquerdo e, ao lado direito, mais 3 (uma embaixo da outra). Como resolvo isso?